# How to execute multiple ajax calls and get the result?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hi I want to execute a batch of ajax calls and get the response and then render the results for the user.

I'm using this code but it is not working because the render function executes before all the ajax responses have been collected.

```
serviceQuery: function (id) {    

   return $.getJSON(SERVICEURL + "/", id);

},

queryService: function(data){

   var self = this;
   var queries = [];
   var results = [];

   $.each(data, function (index, value) {
        queries.push(self.serviceQuery(value.id)); 
   });

   $.when(queries).done(function (response) {

         $.each(response, function (index,val) {

             val.then(function (result){

                 results.push(result[0]);                      

             });

         });

         self.renderResult(results);

   });

},

renderResult: function(results){

     $.each(results, function (index, value) {
     ///Error here cause the value.Name is undefined
          console.info(value.name);
     });

}
```

Any Idea on how to wait for all the ajax calls to finish before execute the render function?

Comment: Read Promises ..promise would be a good fit here , you can use promise.all  here

Comment: Read it many times never found a concret example on how to do it, that is why I'm asking for help.

Comment: Did you try using a callback function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `.apply()` at `$.when()` call to handle an array of `Promise`s. Note also that `.then()` returns results asynchronously

```js
let queries = [
  // `$.ajax()` call and response
  new $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
                                    
    setTimeout(dfd.resolve, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
      // response, textStatus, jqxhr
    , [{name:"a"}, "success", {}])
    })
    // `$.ajax()` call and response
  , new $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
    setTimeout(dfd.resolve, Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000)
      // response, textStatus, jqxhr
    , [{name:"b"}, "success", {}])
    })
];

$.when.apply(null, queries)
.then(function() {
  renderResult($.map(arguments, function(res) {return res[0]}));   
});

function renderResult(results) {
  $.each(results, function (index, value) {
    console.info(value.name);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

Comment: Since arrow functions are not fully supported, let me do de conversion but you example looks good.

Comment: I make the changes but now I'm only getting one result of the array of queries not all of them.

Comment: @DeividKamui Did you include rest parameter `...response` at `.then()`? You can alternatively use `.then(function() { let response = $.makeArray(arguments) })`

Comment: this was my change to the code, can we start a chat? $.when.apply(null, queries).then(function (objResponse) { 
   var dataPros = $.map(objResponse, function (res) {
                        console.info(res);
                        return res[0];
                    });
});

Comment: @DeividKamui `objResponse` would only be first argument of `arguments` at `.then()`. Use `.then(function () { var dataPros = $.map(arguments, function (res) { console.info(res); return res[0]; }); })`

Comment: changing for make array arguments gets to the render but the API response looks a little  weir because is an array[array[arra[actualData]]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148835/discussion-between-deividkamui-and-guest271314).

Answer (score 0):

Change the `$.each` to a `for` loop. It is possible that the `.then` on the value isn't finished processing before the loop completes. `$.each` is synchronous but the `.then` generally, means it's a promise and isn't synchronous.

```
$.each(response, function (index,val) {
    val.then(function (result){
        results.push(result[0]);                      
    });
});
```

Change too

```
for(var idx = 0; idx < response.length; idx++) {
    results.push(response[idx]);
}
```

or keeping with the `each` you may just need to remove the `.then` call.

```
$.each(response, function (index,val) {
    results.push(val[0]);                      
});
```

Comment: let me try this

Answer (score 0):

I see one potential issue here:

```
$.when(queries).done(function (response) {

     $.each(response, function (index,val) {

         val.then(function (result){

             results.push(result[0]);                      

         });

     });

     self.renderResult(results);

});
```

Basically, your pseudocode says this:
For each return value from your $.when() command, take the value of that and return a *new* promise (via `val.then`). However, because you never wait for the val deferred to run, `results.push` is not guaranteed to be called before your `self.renderResult(results)` call.

The code looks weird to me in that you would need two nested deferreds for an ajax call. So I think a larger meta issue is why do you need to do `val.then` in the first place. However, given the current code, you would need to do something like this:

```
var innerDeferreds = [];
$.each(response, function (index,val) {

     innerDeferreds.push(val.then(function (result){

         results.push(result[0]);                      

     }));;

 });
 $.when(innerDeferreds).then(function() { self.renderResult(results); });
```

Again, my guess is that you don't need the `val.then` in the first place, but I would need to look in a debugger to see what the values of `response`, `index` and `val` are. (If you set up a jsfiddle that would be super helpful!)

Comment: Hi I try to use the solution on this question, it was weird for me too the use of double then, but if you do not use it there is no other way to get the response of the API https://forum.jquery.com/topic/the-deferred-way-to-synchronize-lots-of-ajax-responses-with-a-callback